# Flash/AIR Stage3D Texture formats, floating point textures?

Tags: flash, air, 3d, textures, stage3d

What internal texture formats can be set for textures and how?

I'm a bit confused, as the online help for flash.display3d.context3d::createTexture() states:

```
Note that 32-bit integer textures are stored in a packed BGRA format to match the Flash BitmapData format. Floating point textures use a conventional RGBA format.
```

So - floating point textures are supported? but then again, flash.display3D.Context3DTextureFormat has only two constants:

```
BGRA : A texture with colors defined with 8-bit color components in the order: blue, green, red, alpha.
COMPRESSED : A texture in the Adobe Texture Format.
```

whereas the Adobe Texture Format seems to be some 24bit per pixel compressed format.

So - are there any floating point textures (128bit per pixel for RGBA or 32bit for a depth texture or so) supported and if so, how to create them? Is it possible to render into a floating point texture?

how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's impossible to create 128bit texture, since we have no appropriate constant to pass to context3D.createTexture. You can read more here http://forums.adobe.com/message/3714147.